# mouse toggled event isn't responsive on element that supposed to act as nav drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navbar has 3 elements, `image`, `burger-btn` styling, and `<ul>` of 3 items.
When my browser width is 700px or below, I'm hiding my `<ul>` and the `burger-btn` element will be in its place. When I click the button I need a drop-down menu that lists out my unordered list. But, my button isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

I tried `console.log` to check whether my `eventListner` is picking up the mouse click or not, and my function is fired. I'm getting "clicked" when I click the hamburger element.

```js
const hambrugerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburgur");
const nav_list = document.getElementById("nav_list");

function toggledevent() {
  hambrugerBtn.classList.toggle("show");
  console.log("clicked");
  // hambrugerBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

hambrugerBtn.addEventListener("click", toggledevent);
```

```css
.hamburgur {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 10px;
}

.nav_list {
  display: none;
}

.nav_list.show {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
    /* height: 0px; */
  }
  .nav_list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/js/all.js"></script>
<nav>
  <img class="logo" id="funnylogo" src="images/funny_logo-removebg-preview.png" alt="About Section" />
  <button class="hamburgur" id="hamburgur">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
  <ul class="nav_list" id="nav_list">
    <li>
      <a href="#about_me_heading"> About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact/contact.html"> For Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the dropdown selector. Give the button the show class, not the drop-down menu that is placed in the code immediately after the button. This is the `.show + .nav-list` selector.

```js
const hambrugerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburgur");
const nav_list = document.getElementById("nav_list");

function toggledevent() {
  hambrugerBtn.classList.toggle("show");
  console.log("clicked");
  // hambrugerBtn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

hambrugerBtn.addEventListener("click", toggledevent);
```

```css
.hamburgur {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 10px;
}

.nav_list {
  display: none;
}

.show+.nav_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
    /* height: 0px; */
  }
  .nav_list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/js/all.js"></script>
<nav>
  <img class="logo" id="funnylogo" src="images/funny_logo-removebg-preview.png" alt="About Section" />
  <button class="hamburgur" id="hamburgur">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
  <ul class="nav_list" id="nav_list">
    <li>
      <a href="#about_me_heading"> About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact/contact.html"> For Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should add a sufficient explanation. Code-only answers can be considered low-quality as they fail to explain the changes made or how it would solve the issue.

Comment: Dude, you are life saver. Thank you. Can you suggest a good way to work on concepts? I wanna get better in all of HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: @tacoshy I understand. However, it seems ridiculous to me that I get a minus 10 seconds after the answer. Give it time to make a quality answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to post it all together. If you don't have the time to do it, then at least give info that it will be added with an estimated timeframe.

Comment: @useless if you truely want to improve, I would start with semantics. Use semantic tags and work to make your code accessible according to **WCAG 2.1** and if you want to server your website within the EU also **EN 301 549**. It a good and useful practise.

Comment: @tacoshy Realy? Lol. You still offer him the WHATWG specifications to read in the original. 

Comment: What are you talking about? WCAG has nothing to do with the WHATWG, its from W3C. And most norms and accessibiltiy laws such as EN 301 549 are based on the WCAG 2.1. Desptie being accessible, It has a special value for SEO rating... The topic is deeper then you could explain in a few sentences.

Comment: @tacoshy If I'm not joking, I'm saying that everything should be on time. If there are difficulties with understanding selectors, which is basic knowledge in css, then it makes no sense to read the specification at this level. It will only repel the person from further study. However, I am not a teacher. This is just my humble opinion.